# RESTful api queryString functionality

Tags: c#, .net, linq, rest

I'm currently building a C# Web Rest Api, and trying to implement all the CRUD methods as well as a method to filter different fields I have in my Db.

The select all, and the select by Id is done, but I'm curious about how to go about selecting a resource by string.

I'm assuming it would look something like this:

/Api/requests?priority=high

This would search through all of the requests and return all of the requests with the priority set to "high"

Are you then able to combine parameters?

Such as:
/Api/requests?priority=high&status=open

From my understanding these all have to be implemented in their own GET method, but that seems a little excessive.

I've seen a few different implementations of using Lists as well as using GetQueryNameValuePairs, but I'm not sure if those are what I'm looking for.  So, any implementation suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you will be interested in learning more about ODATA which provide an out-of-the-box interface for ad-hoc queries like you describe, over-the-wire via REST. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: Is that the most straight forward way?  I've been looking through SO for most of the day trying to figure out an elegant way to make this work.

Comment: It is pretty straight-forward once the model is built.  Try it out with a very simple model with just one table.  I think you'll find that the query API it presents is quite flexible and comprehensive, saving you the hassle of writing a lot of code to manage the ad-hoc querying.  I know it looks like a lot of setup but it is not bad at all.

Comment: I'll give it a go later tonight.  The code base I'm working with is already using the Entity Framework as well as Code-First migrations and that has been a little irritating to setup initially.  Thanks for giving me some direction! I'll post back with some results.